# Ignore SCM Sensor error

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0

During sonar runner analysis the SVN blame command is executed many times. Sometimes an error happens. The connection might be lost for a moment so that a timeout occurs and the SVN server can't be reached.

The sonar-runner aborts execution when such a error occurs.

Is it possible to configure sonar so that such SVN errors are ignored?

Comment: Does anyone know an answer?

Answer (score 20):

You can use `-Dsonar.scm.disabled=true`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295261/how-can-i-use-git-as-the-scm-provider-in-sonarqube-5-0-using-sonar-runner) for details.