# Git Shallow clone creates lots of warning

Tags: git, jenkins, sonarqube, devops, warnings

I want to use git shallow clone while checking out my repo. My objective is to reduce the Jenkins build time slightly. But the problem is I am getting thousands of warnings on the Jenkins build log. like following

[WARNING] Shallow clone detected, no blame information will be provided. You can convert to non-shallow with 'git fetch --unshallow'.
[INFO] 0/4496 files analyzed
[WARNING] Missing blame information for the following files:

I also get a warning on my SonarQube like this
[image]

how I can get rid of this warning message.

Comment: Related: [SonarQube SCM Integration](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scm-integration/), [SO-37432290](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37432290/16586783)

Answer (score 1):

Shallow clones are faster and smaller because they're skipping a part of the Git history.

Without a full history, it is (in general) impossible to determine who authored a specific part/line of the code.

Bottom line: **if you depend on "blame" information, then you cannot use shallow clones**.

The checkout per-se will work fine, but you're apparently using plugins that depend on this blame information, thus giving the warnings that you see.

Comment: is there any possibility that I want to keep git-shallow clone but want to rid out these warnings as well in my Jenkins build?

Comment: what last 2 lines mean- "The checkout per-se will work fine, but you're apparently using plugins that depend on this blame information, thus giving the warnings that you see."

Comment: You can get rid of the warnings by de-installing all Jenkins plugins that depend on the "blame" information.

Comment: which plugins u mean is responsible for these warnings. Sonarqube plugin u mean??

Answer (score 0):

Blame warnings are part of the SCM plugin for SonarQube. Disable it from Sonarqube can be the solution.
[image]

Comment: My issue is not having warnings. The issue is getting the warnings while it is turned on.