# Sonar-scanner Execution Failure? Java NullPointerException Controller.java EDIT: blame file error

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, sonarqube

Downloaded the scanner package from https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner

The files are right there. Why is sonar so stupid???
[Intellij Terminal after running ---> $sonar-scanner -X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSGp5.png)

Its not actually home-work. I'm grown. I was working on this from my literal home.
[sonar-project.properties file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxJOW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this
[How can I use git as the scm provider in sonarqube 5.0 ( using sonar-runner )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295261/how-can-i-use-git-as-the-scm-provider-in-sonarqube-5-0-using-sonar-runner/28326588#28326588)

led me to this
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/SCM+support

so I set

```
 sonar.scm.disabled=true
```

changed file
[sonar-project.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyMIK.png)

EDIT

That one change to the sonar-project.properties does change whether the sonar-scanner builds successfully or in failure. My best guess is because my project isn't versioned via commits to any platform. It's just a few local files in my IDE and system, and some how its related to disabling sonar.scm function.

```
     #sonar-project.properties file
      sonar.projectKey=my:project
      sonar.projectName=My project
      sonar.projectVersion=1.0

      # Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file.
      #Replace "\" by "/" on Windows.
      #This property is optional if sonar.modules is set.

       sonar.sources=/Users/.../Desktop/homeWork
       sonar.java.binaries=/Users/.../Desktop/homeWork/build/libs/
       sonar.scm.disabled=true
```

Comment: Please format your post. I thought that it is not an answer, but a post with additional data.

Comment: Did that fix the issue ?